# The absence of a "+" sign in fsm editor in the FSM AI Controller package

Tags: unity-game-engine, behavior, fsm

I use the FSM AI Controller package, but when I want to add an ACTION, for the NODE, there is no "+" sign. But when I change the size of the INSPECTOR page, it will be displayed a moment and then hide Please help me

https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/143087-annotation-2019-07-18-034553.jpg

Comment: From the official FSM forums I found out that there is a bug  with Unity 2019.1. They suggest an hotfix here: http://invector.proboards.com/thread/2465/fsm-ai-hotfix-2019-1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it relates to a bug in software.